# .htaccess rewrite rules changing dynamic url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make the url's better for my website for SEO purposes.

Currently pages are displayed like this:

```
SITE/[number]-[page name].html
```

I would like to get the pages to display in a format like below.

```
example 1.
SITE/[page name].html
```

or

```
example 2.
SITE/[page name]-[number].html
```

(I would prefer to leave the page number out if possible, like example 1 but if it must be included I would like it at the end of the url, like the second example above.)

I have the following rule in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*)$ site_page.php?page=$1
```

My biggest problem is that I have tried many ways to get the rewrite to do what I need.
I am a complete newbie when it comes to rewrite.

I have changed the rewrite to the following with no joy.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)$ site_page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9])$ site_page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*+)-([0-9]+)$ site_page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([.*]+)-([0-9]+)$ site_page.php?page=$1
```

The above that I have tried was to keep the page id number, I would preferably like to get rid of the numbers altogether.

I have the following Lines in the setting.php file that controls how the website creates the relevant links. And it displays them as I would like. But I get a 404 error because I think the rewrite rule is not displaying what I expected it to display.

```
// non seo url
$setup_url['normal']['resource']     = "$url_base/site_page.php?page=[number]"; 

// seo url
$setup_url['seo']['resource']    = "$url_base/[number]-[name].html";
```

I have looked at so many articles on mod rewrite rules, and seem to be getting no where. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.
Mark.

Comment: ¿What's the entered URL (Shown in the browser's address bar) and what's the mapped URL? That's not clear in your question, because the rewrite rule is mapping to a PHP script, while your URL examples are mapping to HTML pages.

Comment: mapped url ends for example SITE/site_page.php?page=3 The main files are .php .html is only template files (smarty) and it is just displaying .html rather than url/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you've forgot the `.html` extension in rule.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-(\d+)\.html$ site_page.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. I don't get the 404 any more, but I still cannot get the correct content to display. Now it is just blank. I have been testing further and cannot seem to see where I might be going wrong.

Comment: It might be caused by PHP script. Have you tried to load links like http://domain.com/site_page.php?page=page ?

Comment: loading the links like you said sort of works.(it does not work for a page name on is own, and if you put a number at the beginning or end it uses that only.) I do think possibly the PHP script is causing the problem. I am a bit limited in what I can change as most of the site is ION encrypted. I was thinking that in the .htaccess (.+) might not be giving the desired effect. what if the (.+) included the full link and we then added -(\d) giving us a duplicated number /page-name-number-number.html instead of /page-name-number.html ?

Comment: Looked at mapped url above, try it now.